# How do I make a login/ sign up code for my website using HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: html

I am trying to make a multi user website for Alaskan fishing reports. I am going to find people from different towns, villages/ cities to write reports on their area for other people to learn from. I want to know how to make a system that can keep all the usernames with the passwords assoctiated. I already got the login system done.
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<title> LOGIN Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <style>
   body{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      background:url("log.jpg");
      background-size: cover;
      font-family: sans-serif;
       }
  .log{  width:1366px;
      height:696px;
      
      }
  .loginbox{  width: 320px;
      height: 450px;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      top:20%;
      left:36%;
      position:absolute;
      transform: translate{-50%,-50%}
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 70px 30px;
      opacity:.7;
           }
  .avatar{  width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius:50%;
      position:absolute;
      top:-14%;
      left:calc(50% - 50px);
         }
  h1{    margin:0;
      padding: 0 0 20px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family:AR JULIAN;
      color:red;
    }    
  .loginbox p{  margin:0;
      padding: 0;
      font-weight:bold;
             }
  .loginbox input{width: 100%;
      margin-bottom:20px;
                 }
  .loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
      border: none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
      background: transparent;
      outline:none;
      height:40px;
      color:#fff;
      font-size:16px;
          }
  .loginbox input[type="submit"]{
      border: none;
      outline:none;
      height:40px;
      background:#fb2525;
      color: #fff;
      font-size:18px;
      border-radius:20px;
          }
  .loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover
  {    cursor:pointer;
      background:#ffc107;
      color:#000;
  }
  .loginbox a{   
      text-decoration:none;
      font-size:12px;
      line-height:20px;
      color: darkgrey;
  }
  .loginbox a:hover
  {  
    color:#ffc107;
  }
  .active{
    color:#fff;
    background:#e02626;
    border-radius:4px;
  }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <img class="log">
   <div class="loginbox">
   <img src="avatar1.jpg" class="avatar">
   <h1>Login to Alaska Fishing Reports</h1>

<form>
<p> Username</p>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
<p> Password</p>
<input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
<a href="#">Lost your password?</a><br>
<a href="#">Don't have an acoount?</a>
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ajax-utils.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to register the users in a database. For a web application, it's common to use PHP with MySQL Server. All other data about the users will be saved in the database as well, so you will can get the data of the users associated with them.

Comment: does that cost any money?

Comment: PHP and MySQL Server can be installed on a server or on your local computer (localhost) for free. However, to put your project online, you need to buy a hosting service. You can make your website online in several ways, but the easiest way is to hire a website hosting service, such as HostGator, SiteGround, etc.

Comment: Can't i get google to host it for free?

Answer (score 0):

To create login page, you must learn server side programming, like PHP and MySQL. That might be little complicated and only with HTML CSS and JS you cannot create fully functioning login pages. You should also make security for your clients.